# How to get imageContact from addressBook in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I want get the image of a contact from AddressBook in Swift, but when I try get this I obtain a error: ABPersonIMageFormat is not convertible to ABPropertyID

I don't know how cast this or if this isn't possible how I'm trying..

This is my code:

```
 var addressBook: ABAddressBookRef?
 var contactList: NSArray = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook).takeRetainedValue()

    for record:ABRecordRef in contactList {
        var contactPerson: ABRecordRef = record
        var contactName: String = ABRecordCopyCompositeName(contactPerson).takeRetainedValue() as NSString
        var contactid = ABRecordGetRecordID(contactPerson)

        var image = ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail).takeUnretainedValue()  // Here get the error
```

How can get the image for show this in UIImageView?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ABRecordCopyValue takes an ABPropertyID. To get the image with an ABPersonImageFormat, you need to use ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat:

```
    for record:ABRecordRef in contactList {
        var contactPerson: ABRecordRef = record
        var contactName: String = ABRecordCopyCompositeName(contactPerson).takeRetainedValue() as NSString
        var contactid = ABRecordGetRecordID(contactPerson)

        var image =  ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(contactPerson, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail).takeRetainedValue() as CFDataRef
    }
```

**Update:**
With changes to what `ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat` returns (`Unmanaged<CFData>!`), you can accept `nil` with the following:

```
let image =  ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(contactPerson, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail)?.takeRetainedValue() as CFDataRef!
```

Comment: You are right - Swift and AddressBook have changed a bit since this answer. I updated that line to accept an image if there is one, or nil

Answer (score 1):

You should treat the image data as optional

```
if let imgData =  ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(person, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail)?.takeRetainedValue() {
    let image = UIImage(data: imgData)
    // Contact has image
} else {
    // Contact has not image
}
```